# Passing a variable from BASH to PHP

Tags: php, bash, variables

I'm using a bash script to fire a PHP script but I can't seem to get the variable into PHP...

Bash script where $1=mymusic.mp3

```
php /var/www/html/wave/waveform.php $1;
```

PHP

```
$mp3 = '/var/www/html/processed/' . $argv[1];
copy($mp3, "$tmpname}_0.mp3");
```

The `$argv[1]` variable is just not being received by PHP. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running the bash script? Can you share the entire bash script?

Comment: It's ok, I installed php5-cgi, changed it accordingly and it's working fine now, just couldn't get it to work this way at all.

Comment: You must have [register-argc-argv](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) directive enabled in `php.ini`.

Comment: @baf This was the problem, thank you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691597/passing-a-variable-from-bash-to-php#comment62860686_37691597) that you are using `php5-cgi` to run the script.

`php5-cgi` is the [CGI version](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.cli-cgi.php) of the interpreter; its purpose is to be used by the web server.

If you want to run the script on the command line then you have to use the CLI version of the interpreter. It's name is `php` (or, possibly, `php5` on your system).

The CLI and CGI versions of the interpreter [handle some things differently](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php). The content of the variables [`$argc`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) is one of these differences.

The CGI version populates them only if the [`register_argc_argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) option is set to `On` (or `1`) in `php.ini`. For performance reasons, this option is usually `Off` for the CGI.

On the other hand, the CLI version populates `$argc` and `$argv` variables with the parameters received in the command line no matter the value of `register_argc_argv` option.

As @andlrc also notes in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37695609/4265352), you should enclose `$1` in double quotes when you construct the command line in the shell script, to prevent the shell splitting it into words:

```
php /var/www/html/wave/waveform.php "$1"
```

If, for example, the value of `$1` is `foo bar` (two words), your original usage renders to `php waveform.php foo bar` and `print_r($argv)` displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => waveform.php
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
)
```

On the other hand, if you enclose `$1` in quotes, the command line becomes `php waveform.php "foo bar"` and the shell passes `foo bar` as a single argument to the PHP script. A `print_r($argv)` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => waveform.php
    [1] => foo bar
)
```

---

As a side note, there is a missing `{` in `copy($mp3, "$tmpname}_0.mp3");`. It should probably read "`copy($mp3, "${tmpname}_0.mp3");`

Comment: Maybe it wasn't working as I was using php instead of php5? Just to clarify, what exactly is wrong with the way I'm doing it now if it works without fault? Are there security issues?

Comment: Yes the missing curly bracket was just a typo on here, not in the actual script ;)

Comment: There are differences between the CGI and CLI versions. For example, `$argc` and `$argv` are usually not set by the CGI. Also, it imposes a limit (default: 30 seconds) on the running time of the script; there is no time limit on the CLI version. The CGI also produces HTTP headers that are not needed when running the script using the command line. The CLI version doesn't produce headers (neither implicit nor when the function `header()` is called). For all the differences, please read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Answer (score 2):

`$argv[1]` should work, consider this example:

```
% php -r 'var_dump($argv);' hello
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "-"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

You should however quote `$1` or it will undergo word splitting and globbing:

```
php /var/www/html/wave/waveform.php "$1"
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get this working any way I tried it so in the end I just installed php5-cgi and now call it like this...

BASH

```
php-cgi -f /var/www/html/wave/waveform.php var=$1;
```

PHP

```
$filename = $_GET["var"];
$mp3 = '/var/www/html/processed/' . $filename;
copy($mp3, "$tmpname}_0.mp3");
```

Worked perfectly first time.

Hope it helps somebody else as I wasted a good couple of hours trying to get it working in various other ways without success.

Comment: Beware that [CGI and CLI binaries are not equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php)...